# Mask Ocean or Land from data using Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I would like to mask the Land area from Sea Surface Temperature Data over the globe. I am using Cartopy to plot the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from netCDF4 import Dataset

f = Dataset('sst.mnmean.nc')
sst = f.variables['sst'][0,:,:]
lats = f.variables['lat'][:]
lons = f.variables['lon'][:]

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
plot = ax.contourf(lons, lats, sst, 60, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
cb = plt.colorbar(plot)
plt.show()
```

The above code plots data like this:
[image]

I would like to mask out the Land from this.

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: Please clarify your question, I assume you mean how to remove the temperature data associated with land mass?

Comment: No, the data is actually just ocean data. But in order to be interpolated effectively, the whole globe is used. As a result I have sea surface temperature over land as well (which is meaningless). Sea surface temperatures is a measure of temperature over just the water bodies

Comment: @Maljam How did you edit my question to show the image in the question itself?

Comment: @Kushal there's picture button above the textbox (next to the `{}` button)

Comment: @Maljam Thank you. Just found out that I can't insert pictures until I have a repo of 10. Thanks anyways. Also see the second answer. I figured how to do it. You might get an idea of masking from the picture linked there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I went through the cartopy documentation and came across the method called add_feature. The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy as cart
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from netCDF4 import Dataset

f = Dataset('sst.mnmean.nc')
sst = f.variables['sst'][0,:,:]
lats = f.variables['lat'][:]
lons = f.variables['lon'][:]

ax = plt.axes(projection=cart.crs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cart.feature.LAND, zorder=100, edgecolor='k')
ax.set_global()
plot = ax.contourf(lons, lats, sst, 60, transform=cart.crs.PlateCarree())
cb = plt.colorbar(plot)
plt.show()
```

The plot now looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7erC.png).
To mask the oceans, change `cart.feature.LAND` to `cart.feature.OCEAN`

Comment: Useful solution. But can you advise on using the cart.feature.LAND to mask values in an array, rather than for plotting?

Comment: I'm not sure it is advisable to use cartopy to mask arrays since it is mostly useful for visualization. The reason being the resolution of the data might not match that of the cartopy feature even if you can extract it as an array. I think it is best for you to plot the entire array and do the masking in the plot. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Kushal I think the point of his question is that if you want to use `Cartopy` to mask a contour data but say keep the original background of the basemap

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution does not really mask the data, the plot is simply covered in parts by overlying a map. While this nicely works for the given problem, sometimes an **actual mask** is required to remove unwanted parts of the data. Such a mask can easily be created based on a **rasterized map** for land or ocean.

With the code below, a temporary figure is created, whose resolution corresponds to the given data. After plotting the land map, a [rasterized image](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/rasterization_demo.html) of the map is obtained with `tostring_rgb()`. This image, similar to a binary image, can then be **directly used to create the mask** for the data.

The advantage of this solution is that it can be applied to more general problems, such as plotting two different data sets over land and ocean respectively. The benefit improves when plotting image-like data since transparency can be used to achieve smooth edges by considering the color gradient of the rasterized mask. This can easily be done with `PIL.Image.fromarray(mask)` followed by `convert('L')` and finally applying `putalpha(mask)` on the given image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy
import netCDF4

# load data
data = netCDF4.Dataset('sst.mnmean.nc')
sst  = data.variables['sst'][0,:,:]
lats = data.variables['lat'][:]
lons = data.variables['lon'][:]

# prepare temporary plot and create mask from rasterized map
proj = {'projection': cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(len(lons)/100, len(lats)/100), dpi=100, subplot_kw=proj)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, bottom=0.0, right=1.0, top=1.0)
ax.set_frame_on(False)

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, facecolor='black')
fig.canvas.draw()
mask = fig.canvas.tostring_rgb()
ncols, nrows = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
plt.close(fig)

mask = np.frombuffer(mask, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(nrows, ncols, 3)
mask = mask.mean(axis=2)
sst  = np.where(mask>0, sst, np.nan)

# create actual plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=proj)
ax.contourf(lons, lats, sst, 60, transform=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180))
ax.coastlines()
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Answer (score -4):

For masking land area, it would be easier to use basemap.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
map = Basemap(projection='mill',lon_0=180) # create projection
....                                       # whatever processing needed
map.fillcontinents(color='coral')          # mask land mass
```

[See basemap example here](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/examples.html)

Comment: Basemap is not maintained since a couple of years, and installing it without compromising your environment due to impossible dependencies is a big challenge. A new solution in cartopy, not just for plotting, but also for calculations, would be great.